# How to play Android MediaPlayer using InputStream without tempFile

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to receive an InputStream and play it with MediaPlayer
In 23 and higher, playback was successful using MediaDataSource.
However, under 23, I want to play it without creating a separate tempFile using InputStream.

This is how I tried

this is My Pipe class

```
class MyPipeProvider(private val inputStream: InputStream) {
    private val pipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe()
    
    fun getFileDescriptor(): ParcelFileDescriptor {
        Thread {
            val outputStream = ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(pipe[1])
            try {
                val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                var length: Int
                while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { length = it } != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // error
            } finally {
                inputStream.close()
                outputStream.close()
            }
        }.start()
        
        return pipe[0]
    }

}
```

and MainActivity play MediaPlayer

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener {
   it.start()
}
val pipeProvider = MyPipeProvider(inputStream)
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(pipeProvider.getFileDescriptor().fileDescriptor)
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work
Is there a way to make MediaPlayer play without creating a tempFile using InputStream?